# Using SSIS "Power Query Source" connector to extract Google Analytics data

Tags: google-analytics, ssis

I am trying to get some data with from Google Analytics using SSIS Power Query Source but i am not able to get any data.

It gives me the following message "Credentials are required to connect to GoogleAnalytics source. (Source at GoogleAnalytics)"

Is something missing?

!https://www.dropbox.com/s/on0houhzfn0950g/power_query_source.PNG?dl=0
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43gt2.png)

I extract the "M" code from PowerBI to use it has the source query, then i did the auto detect source and create the new connection.

Comment: Hi & welcome to SO! Can you please post the relevant bits of your code in text form in your question? :)

Comment: Hi, thank you.

Here it is the code that i extracted from Power BI to use in the SSIS component.

let
    Source = GoogleAnalytics.Accounts(),
    #"18060654" = Source{[Id="18060654"]}[Data],
    #"UA-18060654-1" = #"18060654"{[Id="UA-18060654-1"]}[Data],
    #"35854637" = #"UA-18060654-1"{[Id="35854637"]}[Data],
    #"Added Items" = Cube.Transform(#"35854637",
        {
            {Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn, "ga:sessionCount", {"ga:sessionCount"}, {"Count of Sessions"}},
            {Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn,

Comment: "ga:daysSinceLastSession", {"ga:daysSinceLastSession"}, {"Days Since Last Session"}},
            {Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn, "ga:userType", {"ga:userType"}, {"User Type"}},
            {Cube.AddMeasureColumn, "New Users", "ga:newUsers"},
            {Cube.AddMeasureColumn, "Number of Sessions per User", "ga:sessionsPerUser"}
        })
in
    #"Added Items"